# Sumary Field is Blank instead of showing Zero

Tags: crystal-reports

My formula field sums the report. For some of the rows it works correctly and either shows a number or zero. For other sections it doesn't count correctly and comes up blank.

I have checked the details section and there are no null values. I should note that there are other parts of the report where this is displaying properly. How can I fix this?

Comment: Have you established a pattern as to which rows cause the summary to come up blank?

Comment: It appears to be the records that would have null values. However the stored procedure sets the null values to 0 so I'm not sure why that would have an impact.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is indeed caused by null values as you mentioned, you could instead sum on a formula designed to supplant them. If your original field is called `{original_field}` the resulting formula would look like this:

```
IF ISNULL({original_field}) THEN 0 ELSE {original_field}
```

Place this in your details section and suppress it, then rewrite the summary to use the formula instead of `{original_field}` - If that doesn't fix the problem, the null fields aren't causing it.